# Python 3 alternatives for __getinitargs__

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Is there a short enough way to call the `__init__` constructor of a class during unpickling in Python 3? The usual way to do this was using `__getinitargs__` like so

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle

class Car:

    def __init__(self, model, number):
        self.model = model
        self.number = number
        print("constructed with", model, number)
        # many other things to do
       
    def __getstate__(self):
        # intentionally returns None
        pass

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        pass

    def __getinitargs__(self):
        # save some information when pickling
        # (will be passed to the constructor upon unpickling)
        return self.model, self.number

c = Car("toyota", 1234)
d = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(c))
print("reconstructed with", d.model, d.number)
```

However, the `__getinitargs__` will be ignored in new style classes and in Python 3+, all classes can only be new style classes. There is the `__getnewargs__` but it will pass the arguments only to the `__new__` class method which is not the same. A python 2 call of the above illustrative example will result in

```
>> constructed with toyota 1234
>> constructed with toyota 1234
>> reconstructed with toyota 1234
```

while a python 3 call will error out

```
>> constructed with toyota 1234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    print("reconstructed with", d.model, d.number)
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'model'
```

and ignore the `__getinitargs__` method.

I don't think Python 3 will easily regress in that regard so hopefully I am missing something obvious.

**EDIT**: Replacing `__getinitargs__` with `__getnewargs__` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Why do you need to supply `__getinitargs__` in the first place? You can remove the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` and `__getinitargs__` methods here and *it'll just work*.

Comment: This is a simplified example of a much more complicated object. The point of the example was to illustrate the method that is usually used in python 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `pickle` to unpickle your object by calling `Car(self.model, self.number)`, going through `__init__` for initialization the same way a normal call to `Car` would, then tell it to do so in a [`__reduce__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__):

```
def __reduce__(self):
    return (Car, (self.model, self.number))
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/puvKO3).

Comment: Works splendidly - thanks! I just added similar lines to make the code testable but your demo is even more complete. I wish there was a quick mentioning of this in the python version changelog in the official docs but hopefully this answer will also be useful for others.

Comment: @pevogam: Be aware that there are subtle dangers to deserializing objects by calling the constructor, particularly for cases with shared objects or circular references. For example, [this case](https://ideone.com/DI7XMN) calls `ThingHolder.__init__` 3 times, once manually and *twice* in unpickling, even though the object graph it's unpickling only has one `ThingHolder` instance. [This other case](https://ideone.com/sHlKmb) fails completely with a RecursionError, although it [succeeds](https://ideone.com/ceG42I) without `__reduce__`.

Comment: (There are subtle dangers to serialization and deserialization in general, really, but trying to do it by calling the constructor introduces different subtle dangers than trying to do it `pickle`'s default way.)

Comment: I agree with the added undesirable complexity. Unfortunately, the actual class wasn't created by me and contains a lot of unpicklable objects like locks and similar. Thus, having an alternative like this is sometimes useful.

Comment: This is the solution I've been looking for! Like @pevogam, I have a class that I didn't create (specifically a Boost.Python class generated from C++) with MANY unpickable objects. I was trying to use `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`, and `__getinitargs__` and none of them where working. `__reduce__` seems to do the trick!